# Hide Popular / Related Articles on Facebook Instant Article

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-instant-articles

Not all of my Facebook Instant Articles have an image to feature so they will not look good if these articles show up on the 'Popular from ..' section.

Is there a way not to show this section completely?

Comment: No. The most you can do, is specify which of your own articles are related. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/related-articles But if those are missing any featureable images, it might be that they won’t be considered for display there, resp. “look weird.”

Comment: Tried including 4 links myself and they are shown as 'More from ...'. Despite I including these links explicitly, FB is still showing 'Popular from ...'. Why is this so?